# Hide only pressed li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list

```
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="ZoomIn" id="ZoomIn"><input type="button" title="ZoomIn"/></li>
            <li class="Download" id="Download"><input type="button" title="Download"/></li>
            <li class="Play" id="Play" style="display:none"><input class="pressed" type="button" title="Play"/></li>
            <li class="Stop" id="Stop"><input type="button" title="Stop" /></li>
        </ul>
```

This code hide all li elements

```
$("#navigation").click(function(){$("li", this).toggle();});
```

but how to hide only pressed?
I need to toggle Play and Stop, so start with Play display none and then if pressed Stop show Play and Stop hide

Comment: just use $("ul li").click(function(){$(this).toggle();});

Comment: @raghavendra Actually he wants to do that only in the play/stop li.... so no....

Comment: heading says differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#navigation li', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.attr('id') == 'Stop') {
      that.hide();
      $('#Play').show();
    }
    if (that.attr('id') == 'Play') {
      that.hide();
      $('#Stop').show();
    }
});
```

```css
#Play { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navigation">
            <li class="ZoomIn" id="ZoomIn"><input type="button" title="ZoomIn"/></li>
            <li class="Download" id="Download"><input type="button" title="Download"/></li>
            <li class="Play" id="Play" style="display:none"><input class="pressed" type="button" title="Play"/>Play</li>
            <li class="Stop" id="Stop"><input type="button" title="Stop" />Stop</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a click event like this, on li element, then if you do $(this).toggle(), it should toggle clicked li element.

```
$("#navigation li").click(function(){$(this).toggle();});
```